# Normalizing an existing table with strings data

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, foreign-key

I have a table that has two string columns that repeat a lot, and in the next stage, some counts and conditions need to be done, lets say they are called `company_name` and `person_name`.
The table has 200k rows.

I am creating a table for `companies` and `persons`, each has `id, name`.
I also added `company_id_fk` and `person_id_fk` and set FK constraints with nullable default null on the source table.

I have populated the new tables with distinct values from the source table.

Now I am trying to populate the FKs by matching the strings (I couldn't think of any better way!), which looks like this:

```
UPDATE data_table, companies, persons
SET data_table.person_id_fk = persons.id, data_table.company_id_fk = companies.id
WHERE
data_table.company_name = companies.`name`
AND data_table.person_name = person.`name`;
```

This has now been running for 1500 seconds and is still not done.
Am I doing this correctly?
What are the more effective and correct ways to normalize `data_table` and add FKs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involved a few changes:

1. Change all related `text` type columns into `varchar(255)`
2. Add `BTREE` indexes on all the related columns in all 3 tables (some unique, some not)
3. Split the queries into two, one for each column
4. Modify the query to use inner join instead of a cross join:

   UPDATE data_table AS dt
   INNER JOIN persons as p
   ON p.`name` = dt.person_name
   SET dt.person_id_fk = p.id
   ;

   UPDATE data_table AS dt
   INNER JOIN companies AS c
   ON c.`name` = dt.company_name
   SET dt.company_id_fk = c.id
   ;

This has cut it down to 5-7 secs for each!